# Iceland is going on strike because of the gender wage gap. What's their current wage gap when adjusting for hours worked and other variables?

Tags: inequality, gender, income, iceland

As per [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2023/10/23/europe/iceland-women-strike-scli-intl/index.html):

> The strike, which is known as the “Women’s Day Off” or “Kvennafrí” in
> Icelandic, hopes to raise awareness about the “systemic” wage
> discrimination and gender-based violence faced by women in Iceland,
> according to organizers.
>
> Icelandic Prime Minister Katrín Jakobsdóttir told Icelandic news site
> Iceland Monitor on Friday that she will not work on the strike day and
> expects other female members of government to do the same “in
> solidarity with Icelandic women.”
>
> “As you know, we have not yet reached our goals of full gender
> equality and we are still tackling the gender-based wage gap, which is
> unacceptable in 2023. We are still tackling gender-based violence,
> which has been a priority for my government to tackle,” Jakobsdóttir
> said.

When adjusted for hours worked, years of experience, job type and other variables, what's the current wage gap in Iceland? I can find dozens of articles about the planned strike but I can't figure out what the actual wage gap is supposed to be?

Update: I’m well aware that the *unadjusted* figure for Iceland is 21%. I’m specifically looking for the *adjusted* number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the caveat that you'll have to read these source carefully for methodology, which I didn't, the EU nowadays prefers to speak of unadjusted vs unexplained pay gap.  (Although [some sources](https://www.intereconomics.eu/contents/year/2019/number/2/article/the-gender-pay-gap-in-eu-countries-new-evidence-based-on-eu-ses-2014-data.html) still use the older 'adjusted' term for contrast.) It also takes some 5 years for the EU to calculate this unexplained stuff, so in 2023 they [report](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/images/8/88/Gender_pay_gap_statistics%2C_6-March-2023.xlsx) data for 2018. Here's Iceland in comparison with other EU countries in that regard.

[image]

As it so happens, Iceland with 11.2% is exactly on the EU average in that regard. HTH.

Comment: So… Belgium has now achieved full gender equality?

Comment: @JonathanReez: No! It's -0.1% in the actual data. /s

Answer (score -2):

According the the Ney York times there is a 21% difference in the median earnings between Women and Men.

[Women in Iceland to ‘Take the Day Off’ in Protest of Gender Inequality](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/23/world/europe/iceland-equality-strike.html)

> But inequalities have persisted. Parity scores in wages and in representation among senior officials have slipped since 2021 and the numbers are now closer to 2017 levels, according to the World Economic Forum report. The wage gap, which refers to the difference between the median earnings of women relative to the median earnings of men, is 21 percent. A 2018 study from the University of Iceland on the effect of trauma on women’s health found that a quarter of women reported having been raped or having experienced sexual violence.