# Why did the EU stop publishing the adjusted/unexplained wage gap numbers since 2018?

Tags: european-union

The latest EU [report](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/images/8/88/Gender_pay_gap_statistics%2C_6-March-2023.xlsx) on the adjusted/"unexplained" gender wage gap only has data up to 2018.

[image]

Is it known why the EU stopped publishing this data back in 2018? Was it due to lack of funding in the corresponding ministry, political pressure, or perhaps it just takes 5 years to calculate this data retroactively?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82037/iceland-is-going-on-strike-because-of-the-gender-wage-gap-whats-their-current?noredirect=1#comment357333_82037

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The estimates you cite are based on the [Structure of earnings survey (SES)](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/microdata/structure-of-earnings-survey), which is a 4-yearly survey:

> The 4-yearly SES microdata sets are available for **reference years 2002, 2006, 2010, 2014, and 2018**.

It is simply that the 2022 dataset has not been completed and made available for public use yet.

Your assertion that "the EU stopped publishing this data back in 2018" is false and has no basis.

Comment: "your assertion is false" seems needlessly aggressive, considering OP even says "*perhaps it just takes 5 years to calculate this data*" which is in line with this answer.